# Importing source code of a library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, static-libraries

I have a question about importing .java files.

I have downloaded source codes of a library that has many subfolders.

The way that I imported is to create a new folder within my project called libs and dragging dropping the entire folder, after that I right clicked into the libs folder and then clicked Build Path-> Use as Source Folder.

Now the issue is most package names are like "analysis.common.src.java.org.apache.lucene.analysis.ar" whereas within their source code their package name is referred as package org.apache.lucene.analysis.ar;

How can I fix this problem? Using CTRL + SHIFT + O does not fix it.

Comment: Have you tried adding them as source folders in the project build settings?

Comment: @Ash, I forgot to include the fact that I already added them as a source folder and this is an issue that appears after I added them as a source folder.

Comment: Did you try adding the folder above "org", that is, the root of the source folder structure ("java" in the example of "analysis.common.src.java.org.apache.lucene.analysis.ar")?

Comment: @Ash that is the problem there are many folders like that (maybe 100) I don't want t to do it one by one, so is there a way to import them all once?

Comment: Hmm...no, can't find one sorry. The first link from Srikanth below shows how to do it in a graphical manner, you can select all the "root nodes" of the source, but it's still manual, and the folders that are added aren't treated as "source folders" -- you have to right click on them and go Build Path -> Use as source folder. Another way is to close Eclipse, edit the `.classpath` file in the project root and manually enter `<classpathentry kind="src" path="..."/>`. Either way is kind of painful.

Comment: That does not make sense, since this is an apache opensource project, there should be a way to do...

Comment: If the Lucene project (or whatever you're using) comes with an Eclipse .project file, then you can just go Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace. But I assumed surely you'd tried that already.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Eclipse File System Import to import sources to a particular project. [Here](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~kaharris/10200/tutorials/eclipse/Step_04.html) is a step by step explanation.

[Another example](http://www.cs.laurentian.ca/aaron/cosc1047/eclipse-tutorials/import-tutorial.html). Scroll down to `"Importing Files Into a Project"` section

Comment: How are they any different than dragging and dropping? They are essentially the same operation. Therefore it does not solve my problem.